# Arranging Images dynamically in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

U have a Shiny app and I run some analysis on a dataframe and get results like this:

```
brand    %
nike     50 %
adidas   35 %
umbro    15 %
```

Instead of just showing this table in Shiny, is it possible to show the corresponding images (no need to have the numbers) so that they change the order those are shown depending on the applied filter, so the resulting element in Shiny should look like this:

[image]

I will have the images in the wwww folder.

Is this possible with Shiny?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create any output you want with a `uiOutput`. The `renderUI` section on the server allows you to create HTML. This way you can identify which images are in the top 3 (which I did by ordering the data frame woth `order`) and then ouput the ccording images using HTML `<img/>` by using the HTML builder functions from the `htmltools` package.

Test the code and see how the order of the images changes depending on the values by reloading the shiny app.

**Please Note**: this sample will not render the images correctly because I do not know the correct file names they have in your 'www' directory. Adapt the `paste0()` statement to point to the correct path.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Brand Stats"),
    uiOutput("uiTopBrands"),
    h1("Top 3 Brands as Table"),
    tableOutput("tblTopBrands")
)

# Define server logic required to draw the brand stats
server <- function(input, output) {
    df <- data.frame(
      brands = c("nike", "adidas", "umbro", "puma", "reusch"),
      percent = sample(100, 5))
    df$percent <- df$percent / sum(df$percent) * 100
    df <- df[order(df$percent, decreasing = TRUE),]
  
    output$uiTopBrands <- renderUI({
      Output <- tagList(
        h1("Top 3 Brands in Images"),
        p(df$brands[1], "will appear below"),
        img(src = paste0(df$brands[1], ".jpg"), alt = df$brands[1]), # make sure you create the correct url here with "paste0"
        p(df$brands[2], "will appear below"),
        img(src = paste0(df$brands[2], ".jpg"), alt = df$brands[2]),
        p(df$brands[3], "will appear below"),
        img(src = paste0(df$brands[3], ".jpg"), alt = df$brands[3])
      )
      
      return(Output)
    })
    
    output$tblTopBrands <- renderTable({
      df
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.... this is exactly what I needed.